# properties with parameters in C#

Tags: c#, properties

In **VB.Net** Properties can receive arguments as in functions, by mentioning all arguments at the beginning of the property definition:

```
Private m_Address(2) As String
 Property Address(ByVal index As Integer) As String
   Get
     If index >= 0 And index <= UBound(m_Address) Then
       Return m_Address(index)
     End If
   End Get
   Set(ByVal Value As String)
     If index >= 0 And index <= UBound(m_Address( Then
       m_Address(index) = Value
     End If
   End Set
 End Property
```

and If you want to **assign** or read values for properties, send the required arguments in parentheses:

```
Dim hassn As New PersonClass()
 Dim counter As Integer
 hassn.Address(0) = "National Street"
 hassn.Address(1) = "Imbaba neighborhood"
 hassn.Address(2) = "Giza"
 For counter = 0 To 2
   MsgBox(hassn.Address(counter))
 Next
```

I tried to do that using C# but I got this Error:

```
public class Geek
{
    private string[] m_address = new string[2];
    public string[int x] address // error here
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= 0 && index < index.length)
            {
                return m_address;
            }
        }
        set {
            if (index >= 0 && index < index.length)
            {
                m_address = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in C# there is no such thing as [Parameterized Properties](https://web.archive.org/web/20220813071017/https://bettersolutions.com/csharp/framework/framework4-parameterized-properties.htm). The only type of parameterized property you can define in C# is indexer.

A typical C# property has only one default parameter `value`. A property is a set of accessors anyway so you can define these methods instead of using a property:

```
public class Geek
{
    private string[] m_address = new string[2];

    public void setAddress(int index)
    {
         if (index >= 0 && index < index.length)
         {
            m_address = value;
         }
    }

    public void getAddress(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < index.length)
        {
           return m_address;
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to create a class `Address` that encapsulates the field and define a custom indexer that accepts parameters.

Ok let's see how we can use indexer here. First let's create a *class* or *struct* for address:

```
public class Address
{
   private string[] m_address = new string[2];

   public string this[int index]
   {
      get => index >= 0 && index < m_address.Length ? m_address[index] : null;
      set
      { 
          if (index >= 0 && m_address.Length > index)
          {
              m_address[index] = value;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Then let's change your main class to work with Address:

```
public class Geek
{
    public Address Address { get; } = new Address();
}
```

And now you can use indexer for Address property like this:

```
var hassn = new Geek();
hassn.Address[0] = "National Street";
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question i don't think you need "additional parameters". What you need (as it seems), is implementing indexers. You can read about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index

So for your example code would look like this:

```
public class Geek
{
       private string[] m_address = new string[2];
       public string this[int index]
       {
          get { 
              if (index >= 0 && index < index.length)
              {
                  return m_address;
              }
              else
              {
                  return null;
              }
          }
          set { 
              if (index >= 0 && index < index.length)
              {
                  m_address = value;
              }
          }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Fabjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4995012/fabjan) notes C# has a more restricted version of this.

To define an indexer use `this`:

```
public string this[int x] {
  get => underlyingCollection[x];
  set {
    if (valueValue(value) {
      underlyingCollection[x] = value;
    } else {
      throw new ArgumentException(…);
    }
  }
}
```

Note you can overload on the index argument (eg. to support `string` and `int` indices).